# Question on index of two subgroups in a chain

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $%
N_{G}(P)=N_{0}<...<N_{r}=G$, be a chain of subgroups of $G$.

Is it true that $|N_{i+1}:N_{i}|\equiv 1$ (mod $p$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is because by Sylow's theorems you have
$$
\lvert N_{i} : N_{0} \rvert \equiv 1 \pmod{p}
$$
for all $i$. In fact, $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_{i}$ and
$$
N_{0} = N_{G}(P) = N_{N_{i}}(P).
$$

Thus for all $i$
$$
1 \equiv \lvert N_{i+1} : N_{0} \rvert 
=
\lvert N_{i+1} : N_{i} \rvert \cdot \lvert N_{i} : N_{0} \rvert 
\equiv
\lvert N_{i+1} : N_{i} \rvert 
\pmod{p}.
$$

Comment: @St-W, you're welcome!